# NGROK failed to start the tunnel

Tags: shopify, ngrok

I have been trying to run the shopify app in my local machine, but this error keeps popping up.
"Ngrok failed to start the tunnel"

Ngrok is successfully installed in my system, and env variable is also set to correct location.

Comment: I'm having the same problem collaborating with my team, the only documentation I found was your question and its recent as well so it makes me think it has to be a recent ngrok update or shopify issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a different version of `@shopify/app` and `@shopify/cli`. I had the same problem with version `3.14.0` and I used `3.21.0`. This solved my problem.

```
"@shopify/app": "3.21.0",
"@shopify/cli": "3.21.0",
```